Do the points in a closed Lorentzian manifold at which the exponential map is undefined on some spacelike vector form an open set?
Consider a connected closed (i.e. compact and without boundary) Lorentzian manifold $M$. If the exponential map at $p \in M$ is undefined on some spacelike vector of $T_p M$, is the same necessarily true for every $p'$ in some open neighborhood of $p$?
I am interested because my research topic involves flat conformal Lorentzian geometry, and because Fried seems to take advantage of this fact for Riemannian manifolds in his paper Closed similarity manifolds, for the purpose of constructing a certain canonical metric on an incomplete closed Euclidean similarity manifold (there defined as a kind of $(G, X)$ manifold).
I am inclined to think the answer is not necessarily, but I do not know how to construct a counterexample, and I haven't yet built a lot of specific knowledge about Lorentzian metrics of a more general variety. Sánchez's An Introduction to the Completeness of
Compact Semi-Riemannian Manifolds seems to be a useful general reference for this question. The references given there include a number of papers involving examples of Lorentzian manifolds that shed light on the various relationships between different completeness assumptions. I have only looked through some of these references, but I have not yet recognized in them a counterexample for the question above.
Edit: I should add that I believe the question is not vacuous because the example surrounding line (1) of Galloway's Compact Lorentzian Manifolds Without Closed Nonspacelike Geodesics describes a Lorentzian torus which is spacelike geodesically incomplete.
